# Request for Assistance with CPAU command in azure pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, runas

I am currently attempting to run a Windows Azure pipeline in which a specific job requires executing a command under a different user account. To accomplish this, I am using the CPAU ([www.joeware.net](http://www.joeware.net)) command.

However, I have encountered an issue when running the self-hosted agent as a service. If the user account I used to log in differs from the one specified in the CPAU command line, it results in an error (-1073741502). The problem does not occur if I input the same username and password as the admin accound that runs the self-hosted agent in the CPAU command.

It's important to note that everything works as expected when the scripts are launched either in the local session or with the self-hosted agent in interactive mode.

I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions you might have to address this issue when working with a self-hosted agent as a service.

```
name: $(Rev:r)
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: self
    type: git
    name: "git_repos"
stages:
- stage: __default
  jobs:
  - job: Job
    variables:
    - name: step_display_name
      value: Run as another user
    strategy:
      matrix:
        Windows:
          demanded_agent_os: Windows_NT
    pool:
      name: test
      demands:
      - Agent.OS -equals $(demanded_agent_os)
    workspace:
      clean: outputs
    steps:
    - task: 6d15af64-176c-496d-b583-fd2ae21d4df4@1
      inputs:
        repository: self
        submodules: recursive
    - task: CmdLine@2
      displayName: $(step_display_name)
      inputs:
        script: |
          RMDIR /s /q C:\foo
          MKDIR C:\foo
          CALL C:\CPAU\cpau.exe -u DOMAIN\another.username -p "$(userPassword)" -ex "cmd.exe /c echo print bar file > C:\foo\bar.txt" -wait -lwp -outprocexit -cwd C:\
          IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 (
            ECHO %ERRORLEVEL%
            EXIT /B 1
          )
          TYPE C:\foo\bar.txt
```

With this example, when the self-hosted agent runs in interactive mode the job is successful, but fails in service mode with error code: "-1073741502".

Comment: Refer to this note: https://www.joeware.net/freetools/tools/cpau/usage.htm The primary intent of thisapplication is to allow interactive logons to switch security context for specific
processes, not crutch unattended applications working for web apps and from the task scheduler. It may need to use Interactive mode agent job to execute it. When the job runs as service, it will have limitation

Comment: Thank you, @KevinLu-MSFT , for pointing that out. I tried PsExec (https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/sysinternals/downloads/psexec) instead and managed to achieve my goal.